# Unable to use Visual Studio Code Coverage with Azure Functions

Tags: visual-studio, azure, code-coverage, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio 15.3.5 and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.6.

I can run tests fine, but when I analyze the tests with Code Coverage the assembly which contains the Azure Functions is not analyzed. It is not listed in the Code Coverage assembly list. Other assemblies are listed, only the Azure Functions assembly is omitted.

Have anyone got it working?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "Azure Functions assembly"? Do you mean the Functions Runtime, or your own assembly containing your functions?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant my own assembly containing the functions.

Comment: I'll ask VS Functions expert. As a test, if you add a helper library (so a different assembly), does that one get included in the code coverage results?

Comment: One theory is that code coverage may be broken with the new project system (which Function project uses). What type of Class Library project did you try? Does it still work if you choose *Class Library (.NET Standard)* instead of *Class Library (.NET Framework)*? If not, that would further validate that theory.

Comment: How do you see the code coverage?  What are the steps you are taking to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that for new project types, the default `<DebugType>` is portable, which means that the pdb's generated would not have required info needed for CodeCoverage.

Here is how you can change this: in your .csproj, add `<DebugType>full</DebugType>` to the `<PropertyGroup>`. e.g. you should have:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or you can change this from VS:

- go to properties on the project
- go to the build tab, then the “Advanced…” button at the bottom
- there’s a dropdown for Debugging Information. Setting that to “Full” updates the project with the necessary property

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you very much! Any idea when/if this will be fixed out of the box?

Comment: @Eric not sure about that. I'll check with the Code Coverage people, as they may have had a reason to set the default the way they did.

Comment: @Eric looks like it will eventually just work, but that may not happen for a few months. For now, use the workaround :)